# How to send multiple notifications with different category identifiers using Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications

I have to send two different notifications each with a different category identifier.

When I only set one of these notifications, the actions show up properly. However if I set both of the notifications to sometime in the future, the second one will have proper actions.

```
if(condition){
        var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
        content.Title = "Notification1";
        content.Body = "blah blah balh";
        content.Badge = 1;
        content.CategoryIdentifier = "cat1";

        var requestID = pos1.ToString();
        var date = new NSDateComponents();
        date.Hour = this.time.Hour;
        date.Minute = this.time.Minute;
        date.Weekday = i + 1;
        var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(date, true);

        var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (error) => {
            if (error != null) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error.LocalizedDescription ?? ""}");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Scheduled alarm for " + date);
            }
        });
        // Create actions
        var action1 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier("action1", "Action1", UNNotificationActionOptions.Foreground);
        var cancelID = "cancel";
        var cancel_title = "Cancel";
        var cancel_action = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier(cancelID, cancel_title, UNNotificationActionOptions.Destructive);

        // Create Category
        var actions = new UNNotificationAction[] { action1, cancel_action };

        var intentIDs = new string[] { };
        var categoryOptions = new UNNotificationCategoryOptions[] { };
        var category = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier("cat1", actions, intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.None);

        // Register Category
        var categories = new UNNotificationCategory[] { category };
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories(new NSSet<UNNotificationCategory>(categories));
    }
if(condition2){
        var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
        content.Title = "Notification2";
        content.Body = "blah";
        content.Badge = 1;
        content.CategoryIdentifier = "Cat2";
        var requestID = pos2.ToString();
        var date = new NSDateComponents();
        date.Hour = this.time.Hour;
        date.Minute = this.time.Minute;
        date.Weekday = i + 1;
        var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(date, true);

        var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (error) => {
            if (error != null) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error.LocalizedDescription ?? ""}");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Scheduled alarm for " + date);
            }
        });
        var action2 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier("action2","Action2", UNNotificationActionOptions.Foreground);
        var cancelID = "cancel";
        var cancel_title = "Cancel";
        var cancel_action = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier(cancelID, cancel_title, UNNotificationActionOptions.Destructive);

        // Create Category
        var actions = new UNNotificationAction[] { action2, cancel_action };
        Console.WriteLine(this.time + actions[0].ToString());
        var intentIDs = new string[] { };
        var categoryOptions = new UNNotificationCategoryOptions[] { };
        var category = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier("Cat2", actions, intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.None);

        // Register Category
        var categories = new UNNotificationCategory[] { category };
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories(new NSSet<UNNotificationCategory>(categories));
}
```

When just condition or condition2 is true, one notification will be sent properly, with two of the actions showing. When both conditions are true, both notifications will be sent however only the second notification will have actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the document about the [UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649512-setnotificationcategories?language=objc):

> Call this method at launch time to register your app’s actionable
>   notification types. This method registers all of your categories at
>   once, **replacing any previously registered categories with the new one**s
>   in the categories parameter. **Typically, you call this method only
>   once.**

You called this function **twice** in your code and the second call will **replace** your first call. That's the reason why only the second one have proper actions.

**Solution** is call this function only once and register all the categories at that time.